# Where to use =like operator? Difference between like and =like?

Tags: python, odoo

Where to use `like` and `=like` operators in openerp. What is the difference between these two?

I want use `=like` in an openerp method for string matching. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use the `=` operator, the result will be the given string with [prefixes] and/or [suffixes]. For example:

Domain with `like`:

```
[('name', 'like', 'tangaraj')]
```

This domain will give you records whose name is *tangaraj*, *tangaraja*, *anyprefixtangarajanysuffix*, etc... but it will not give you *Tangaraj*, because it distinguishes between uppercase and lowercase.

Domain with `=like`:

```
[('name', '=like', 'tangaraj')]
```

This one will give you only records whose name is *tangaraj*, as the `=` operator will do.